# Help identifying insulation

Tags: insulation

A building I was in a while back had some suspicious-looking insulation. Spent maybe half an hour in there. I didn't do any of the demolition. Can anyone identify whether or not this could be asbestos?

I understand that it can be hard/impossible to identify without a lab test so I plan to reach out to the building owner too. I'm slightly worried about it since I was only wearing a non-surgical mask. Would appreciate any input.

Building location Ontario, built around the 1970s.

[image: insulation]

Comment: Vintage of building, location would give hints, though a test is the gold standard. That said, brief exposure isn’t likely to be an issue.

Comment: Not trying to downplay your concerns, but 30 minutes anywhere isn’t going to be a problem. Plus, 70s Ontario bodes  well for non-asbestos generally.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm curious as to why 70s Ontario reduces the chance of there being asbestos?

Comment: Good for you for calling me on that. My fuzzy memory was that they were phasing out sprayed insulation containing asbestos in the 60s; however, in some cases that lasted into the 80s. Sprayed insulation, as long as you weren’t scraping it, is pretty inert, though. And I come back to my original point: 30 minutes is nothing in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: The only reason people fear asbestos is because there are trust funds to pay mesothelioma victims, and so lawyers spam cheap TV channels because it's an easy payday.  If it wasn't for that, you'd have never heard of the stuff.  However, the only way to get mesothelioma is to work around asbestos *as a career for 10 years* and refuse to wear a mask.  Next time you're in a place like that just don your COVID mask.

Comment: The building was being demolished so I was mainly worried about there being asbestos fibers in the air. I also didn't keep track of which clothes I wore that day so that isn't really helping my concerns. Thank you both for your input - perhaps I'm getting a little too concerned.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the only ones who can identify whether or not this is asbestos is a lab qualified to test for asbestos. Nobody can tell (not even lab employees) by looking at a pic, especially not a wide pic like this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*A building I was in a while back*

Were you working in the building for hours or days? Demolishing it or renovating it?

Or did you just pass through for a few minutes?

Asbestos is very dangerous if you are around it for a long time - hour after hour, day after day, year after year. Especially if you are working with the material - demolishing buildings, renovating buildings, etc.

On the other hand, if you were just passing through for a few minutes and were not breathing in a huge cloud of dust (which even a very basic mask would block most of it anyway), it is not *likely* to be a real concern. Kind of like how one cigarette, or even one pack of cigarettes, isn't likely to give you emphysema or lung cancer. Even though a pack a day of those same cigarettes for 50 years straight *is* likely to give you emphysema or lung cancer.

Not risk-free to pass through a little asbestos occasionally, but not exactly high-risk.

Same for radon. Same for a lot of environmental hazards. (Exception: carbon monoxide can kill you pretty quickly, which is why CO alarms are a very important thing if you have any combustion appliances in your home.)

Comment: Post amended to answer your question. Appreciate the input